# segmentation fault on regex function

Tags: c, regex, pointers, struct

If I had this code all inside just one function, I could get everything working fine, but now my problem is that I can't read the results of my regex. When I try printing the first result, I get a segmentation fault. Instead, I was expecting the first regex result to appear of "T/2/b".

Also, the word "Matches" appears on the screen right before the segmentation fault occurred.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>

typedef struct{
    char str[1000];
} regex;

long regexmatch(const char* str,const char* regexs,size_t nummatch,regex** reg){
    regex_t r;regmatch_t match[nummatch];
    if (regcomp(&r,regexs,REG_EXTENDED) != 0){return -1;}
    if (regexec(&r,str,nummatch,match,0)!=0){regfree(&r);return -1;}
    size_t i=0;
    for (i=0;i<nummatch;i++){
        if (match[i].rm_so > -1){
            memset((**reg).str,0,1000);
            memcpy((**reg).str,(char*)(str+match[i].rm_so),match[i].rm_eo-match[i].rm_so);
            (*reg)++; //this is where I load the result into the struct and advance the pointer.
        }
    }
    char *p=(**reg).str;
    *p='\0';
    regfree(&r);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char buf[1000];
    memset(buf,0,1000);
    regex* r=(regex*)buf;
    if (regexmatch("T/2/b","([A-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)",10,&r)==0){
    printf("Matches\n");
    printf("%s\n",r->str); //causes segmentation fault. Expecting a "T/2/b" to be displayed instead.
    }
}
```

Comment: Which sub-species of regex code are you using?  It looks like it might be POSIX [`regcomp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) et al, but it is as well to be explicit.

Comment: Did you compile with `address-sanitizer` or run under `valgrind`?

Comment: posix extended version of regex

Comment: I used strace and it shows segmentation fault right after the word "matches". so this line `printf("%s\n",r->str);` is causing the segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, I don't care what your interpretation of the `strace`-result is. I compiled this with `address-sanitizer` and it showed stack corruption in `regexmatch()`.

Comment: That's odd because I made tests by adding a `printf("V=%s\n",(**reg).str);` before `(**reg)++` and the data output is fine in the function. I did increase the buffer size from 1000 to 100000 to stop the segmentation faults but the data still isn't showing in the main function which is where I want it.